# ng-file-upload file.$valid is undefined

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I'm trying to implement file uploading using the Angular [ng-file-upload[(https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) directive. I've followed the docs as closely as possible. I want the user to be able to fill in a form, attach an image, and hit the submit button. When that occurs, I then want to send the file and form input fields as json to the server.

When I run my check to see if `image.$valid` is true, I get an error ``. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Here is my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate','ui.bootstrap', 'ngFileUpload']);

app.controller('NewPostQuestionCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'Upload', function($scope, $http, Upload) {
    $scope.image = {};
    $scope.form = {};
    $scope.postQuestion = {
        token: $scope.token,
        employer_id: $scope.employer_id,
        question: $scope.question,
        published: $scope.published
    };

    $scope.submit = function(postQuestionAttributes, image) {
        console.log(postQuestionAttributes.$valid)
        console.log(image.$valid)
        if (image && image.$valid && !image.$error && postQuestionAttributes.$valid) {
            $scope.upload(image, postQuestionAttributes);
        }
    };

    $scope.upload = function(file, postQuestionAttributes) {
        Upload.upload({
            url: 'cms/posts',
            fields: postQuestionAttributes,
            file: image
        }).progress(function (evt) {
            var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
            console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.file.name);
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('file ' + config.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + data);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('error status: ' + status);
        })
    };
}]);
```

Here is my form:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" name="form.postQuestionForm" ng-submit="submit(postQuestion, image)" class="new_post_item" novalidate>
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" ng-model="postQuestion.token" ng-init="postQuestion.token='<%= form_authenticity_token %>'">
    <input name="employer_id" type="hidden" ng-model="postQuestion.employer_id" ng-init="postQuestion.employer_id='<%= current_employer.id %>'">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Question</label>
        <textarea class="question-textbox" name="question" ng-model="postQuestion.question" required></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Image</label>
        <div class="button" ngf-select ng-model="image" name="image" ngf-pattern="image/*" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="150KB" required>Select</div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Publish Question</label>
        <select class="" name="published" ng-model="postQuestion.published" required>
            <option value="true">Publish</option>
            <option value="false">Don't Publish</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <input class="submit-btn" name="commit" type="submit" value="Publish Post" ng-disabled="form.postQuestion.$invalid">
</form>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I don't get any errors.

Comment: the docs are not quite clear about what `$valid` does ): Have you tried using `$file.$error`? It shows validation errors too, so if it exits the file is not valid.

Comment: Yeah, the docs on `$valid` are certainly lacking. I figured out the problem (I think). I was calling `$valid` on `postQuestionAttributes`, when I really should have been calling it on `$scope.form.postQuestionForm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$valid is for the form element not the file, so you can have `$scope.form.image.$valid` but the file itself would just have the `$error` related to that individual file.
So in your submit code check for `$scope.postQuestionForm.image.$valid` instead of `image.$valid`.

But they are all seems redundant checks so in your case checking the validity of the form itself which would mean the all the elements in the form are valid would be enough:

```
$scope.submit = function(postQuestionAttributes, image) {
    if ($scope.postQuestionForm.$valid) {
        $scope.upload(image, postQuestionAttributes);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

form object is map , where fields are keys with validation result , so to check if individual input like name="image" is valid or not you must do like this:

```
var is_valid = form.postQuestionForm["image"].$valid;
```

here is small jsfiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/nran9uhh/2/

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't have any effect. I'm still getting `undefined` when I call `image.$valid`